# Is it possible to add a new node to an existing edge using Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to implement the Game of Sprouts using python and the networkx library. The idea of the game is you start with two vertices. A player draws an edge from one vertex to another. A new node is placed on that newly created edge. The rest of the game's details aren't necessary but I placed a link at the bottom to further explain it. Currently, I first create a node, then add an edge from the starting node to this new node. Next, I add another edge from the new node to the terminating node. My question is, is there an easier way of accomplishing this? For instance, drawing the edge first and then placing a new node on this edge.

http://nrich.maths.org/2413

Comment: The vertex exists while you are drawing the edge, it just looks different, and ends by being drawn differently, or the edge being attached to another vertex, and the construction one being deleted.

Comment: No vertex or edge gets deleted. I don't think I fully understand your comment. Every-time an edge is drawn a new node must be placed on that edge. Now you can draw an edge from any of the existing nodes including the new one. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can use [add_path()](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.add_path.html) function.

**Example:**

```
>>> g = nx.Graph()
>>> g.add_nodes_from( [0,1] )
>>> g.nodes()
[0, 1]
# We have two nodes, zero edges.
# User clicks two vertices, say 0 and 1.
# We add one more node first.
>>> g.add_node(2)
# Then we add the new edges
>>> g.add_path([0,2,1])
>>> g.nodes()
[0, 1, 2]
>>> g.edges()
[(0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks man, thats the idea I was working with too just using add_edge() twice. add_path() simplifies this and is essentially what I want.