# Add node between existing edge in Networkx Graph generated by OSMnx

Tags: python, networkx, shapely, osmnx

I have gotten sensor location data from *Highway England*. I want to **add** these **sensor locations to OSM multidigraph**. How to do that?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
```

Graph data is
`graph = ox.graph.graph_from_bbox(52.2, 51.85, -.6, -0.9, network_type='drive', simplify=False)`

I want to add `sensor = Point(-0.6116768, 51.8508765)` on the edge nearest to it. Nearest edges to this sensor is `n_edge = osmnx.distance.nearest_edges(graph, -0.6116768, 51.8508765, return_dist=False)`. Now, I need to bend this *n_edge* such that it passes through the given ***sensor point***.

I found a way to solve this issue by creating a **new node** in graph, `graph.add_node('sensor25', y= 51.8508765, x= -0.6116768, street_count = 2)` then `graph.add_edges_from([(n_edge[0], 'sensor25'), ('sensor25', n_edge[1)])`. However, the node created by me (***sensor25***) is not identical to other nodes. How to make this node **similar to existing nodes**?

I have went through following questions

- [add attribute to node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783652/adding-an-attribute-to-a-node-in-osmnx)
- [add new node to existing edge in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172359/is-it-possible-to-add-a-new-node-to-an-existing-edge-using-networkx)
- [add random nodes on edges manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71437958/can-i-add-random-nodes-on-edges-manually-in-osmnx).

Comment: So do you want to add an additional node to your network?

Comment: Thanks, yes I added a node by using graph.add_node(). Now, I want this node to lie on the nearest edge to it. Let's assume the nearest edge is (320774090, 10394004) then I want this new node as (320774090, new_node, 10394004) if edge is one-way or two way, otherwise (10394004, new_node, 320774090) if traffic flow is opposite.

Comment: So you need to add edges I think, because you can't connect an already existing edge, that is already connected to two nodes, to a new node without modifying this edge, in other words you would be changing the edge (breaking it into two)

Comment: Thansk for a comment. 1] Geometry of edge is LineString. If I can add this sensor as a point in the LineString of given edge then that would work as well. 2] If I can find projection of this sensor on the edge and rename that point as sensor then that works as well. 3] Yes, if I can break existing edge in two different edges that would also be good.

Comment: So I understand this correctly, given a sensor node, you want to add it to the nearest edge, and you are allowed to destroy this given edge so it passes through your new node and the previous ones? Also what do you mean by the node you added is not identical to the others in the rest of the network?

Comment: Yes, you understood this correctly. If I am adding or making new edges it must be consistent with the rest of the network like new edges must be having consistent speed_limit, length, street number, oneway, etc. However, the node I added has only x,y, ref, geometry, and street count.

Comment: So can't you save the attributes of the edge you're about to change, then change the edge and add back the copied attributes?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I exactly wanna do that but I am not able to do it.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you need, what I understand: You want to add new edges with attributes: `speed_limit`, `length`, `street number` `one way`, copied from the edge you delete?

I assume that some of these attributes can be copied 1:1, like `one way`, while others will have to be recalulated. For simplicity, let's assume we have a function `d(a, b)` that takes (graph) nodes `a` and `b`, extracts their position, and calculates the air distance between them. Define other functions as required.

Then you could e.g. define the new edge like this:

```py
# Get from/to id of closest edge
f, t = osmnx.distance.nearest_edges(graph, -0.6116768, 51.8508765, return_dist=False)[0]
c = 'sensor25' # Id of new node, c as in 'center'

edge_attrs = g[f][t] # Copy edge attributes
g.remove_edge(f, t) # Remove edge from graph
graph.add_node(c, y= 51.8508765, x= -0.6116768, street_count = 2)

# Add new edges, recalculating atttributes as required
g.add_edge(f, c, **{**edge_attrs, 'length': d(f, c)})
g.add_edge(c, t, **{**edge_attrs, 'length': d(c, t)})
```

Hope the syntax is clear, otherwise ask. It copies edge_attrs 1:1, except for attributes you specify after, like `lenght`. Probably you will have to define multiple functions like `d`, that also calculate the geometry etc.

The code isn't tested.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tested and it works!, but the only problem I see, is that you also have to recalculate the "form" of the edge. Sometimes the edge in a road network is continuous but has like twists, tilts. With this code, It places the node in the edge but it will link itself with the other nodes with a straight line.